# Comparing Proportions of Segmented Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion, contingency-tables

Suppose I have an overall proportion (say people who smoke and have resulted to cancer): `0.01630426` (across all dimensions considered together), Now I segment the data and say for a dimension 1 (if he has a family history of cancer) the proportion is `0.0345`. How can I test if the latter proportion is significantly different from the overall proportion?

Is the proportion test still valid? If not what can I do to arrive at statistical significant answer about the difference, please note that I have both the numerator and denominator values for the proportion computations.

Should I do a Chi-Squared between people with family history of cancer vs. people without such history and see for significance? But I want to compare it to the overall proportion.

Simply put how do I say statistically that my segmented view has resulted in a better proportion than the overall proportion?

Comment: A test that compares a subset of the complete data vs the complete data would not be a valid test. Why not test two things: first, whether the proportion 0.0345, for instance, is significantly different from zero, and second, whether that proportion is significantly different (two-tailed) or higher (one-tailed) than the proportion associated with families with no history of cancer?

Comment: Thanks @DJohnson, I was thinking on similar lines, but to be a bit safe I am avoiding the proportion test because I do not want to assume normality and hence a non-parametric choice of test like Chi-Square following similar approach. Comments are invited.

Comment: Sure. That would be akin to treating your data as a contingency table for testing. Lots of excellent literature out there about those. One I like is Wickens' Multiway *Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences*.